# Git plumbing commands to detect submodule update and get the hashes in staging area or working directory

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-plumbing

In porcelain mode, `git diff` advertises submodule changes:

```
$ cd /opt/staging # This is the main Git repository
$ cd software/zemke-rhyne # This is a submodule
$ git pull
$ git diff                                                                                                                  
diff --git a/software/zemke-rhyne b/software/zemke-rhyne
index 0fff2fc..cb69287 160000
--- a/software/zemke-rhyne
+++ b/software/zemke-rhyne
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 0fff2fc52bdc2a62a2647110e712b1b3baa48613
+Subproject commit cb69287a3540054ff85cd14199cf36b4b5098c1a
```

What plumbing commands could give the following information?

- the submodule updated, here software/zemke-rhyne
- the old hash, here 0fff2fc52bdc2a62a2647110e712b1b3baa48613
- the new hash, here cb69287a3540054ff85cd14199cf36b4b5098c1a

The goal is for example to automate a commit message to briefly document the changes in the updated submodule through git rev-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find out whether the submodule was updated, you can use

```
$ git diff-files --quiet software/zemke-rhyne
```

The exit status will indicate whether the submodule is up-to-date (0) or out-of-date (1).

The old hash is shown for example by `ls-tree`:

```
$ git ls-tree @ software/zemke-rhyne
160000 commit 0fff2fc52bdc2a62a2647110e712b1b3baa48613  software/zemke-rhyne
```

Another way would be

```
$ git ls-files -s software/zemke-rhyne
160000 0fff2fc52bdc2a62a2647110e712b1b3baa48613 0   software/zemke-rhyne
```

(What's the difference? Would be great if somebody could comment…)

There's also a way to find out both whether the submodule was updated *and* the previous hash. If the submodule is unmodified, the following command's output is empty, otherwise it looks like this:

```
$ git diff-files software/zemke-rhyne
:160000 160000 0fff2fc52bdc2a62a2647110e712b1b3baa48613 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 M  software/zemke-rhyne
```

Unfortunately, `diff-files` misses a perfect opportunity of also showing the updated hash. To see it, all I could come up with is to use `rev-list` in the submodule directory. This seems a little inelegant and fragile…

```
$ git -C software/zemke-rhyne rev-list -n 1 @
cb69287a3540054ff85cd14199cf36b4b5098c1a
```

Comment: An example of @joki method in action: https://devcentral.nasqueron.org/P289 (`get_old_hash` and `has_submodule_been_updated` methods)